# Entity frame work CreateDatabase() methode does not create stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server 2008 DBMS, and I have created an EDM (generated from the database), my application is almost finished and everything works great.

However, in my application, I want to let the end-user create the database so I created a form to let the user specify the server and database name and provided a create button. When the user clicks the create button, a new database is created on the specified server. To do this, I have used the `CreateDatabase()` method like this:

```
string connString = ...;
MyEntity context = new MyEntity(connString);
context.CreateDatabase();
```

The code works and the database is created. My problem is that this method does not create stored procedures. Please help me and let me know if there is another way to do this.

P.S.: when I generated the EDM from the database, I chose it to be included in the EDM and I used the function import to use this stored procedure in my code to ensure that it is included in my EDM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will never ever create stored procedures for you. How should EDMX know what logic was included in stored procedures? One characteristic of stored procedures is that they wrap / hide their implementation so the caller knows only the name, parameters and result but not internals. You must include creation script for stored stored procedures as separate file / resource and execute it after the database is created.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry this was a stupid question how i didn't think of that.thank you very much